# Permission changes after extracting tgz file

Tags: centos, tar, compression

While extracting a `tgz` file, I have noticed that the permission changes to something weird! The tgz file belongs to root:root however, the folder belongs to 502:games

```
[root@rocks7 common]# ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4779534 May  2  2012 scalapack-2.0.2.tgz
[root@rocks7 common]# tar xf scalapack-2.0.2.tgz
[root@rocks7 common]# 
[root@rocks7 common]# ls -l
total 98576
drwxr-xr-x 10  502 games     4096 May  2  2012 scalapack-2.0.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   4779534 May  2  2012 scalapack-2.0.2.tgz
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: consider gnu tar's `--no-same-owner`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The tarball contains a `scalapack-2.0.2` directory owned by user id 502 and whatever group id corresponds to the games group (or, perhaps, the games group by name). You can see this by running

```
tar tvf scalapack-2.0.2.tgz
```

Tar archives store ownership and permissions in addition to the file contents; since you’re extracting as root, that metadata is applied to the extracted files. The ownership of the tarball itself has no impact on the ownership of the extracted data.

Since you’re running CentOS, you’re presumably running GNU `tar`, and you can use the `--no-same-owner` and `--no-same-permissions` options to extract tarballs without applying the stored ownership and permissions. Other `tar` implementations may have similar options (*e.g.* `-o` on [FreeBSD `tar`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tar&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%2012-current&arch=default&format=html)).

Comment: POSIX `pax` has the (standardized) option `-p p` (`p`reserve only `p`ermissions) for that.